# Logstash Mutate

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, filebeat

I'm setting up ELK stack, and the following settings

```
mutate {
  id => "adding_fields"
  add_field => {
    "host" => "foo-%{[beat][version]} baz"
    "custom" => "Hello, 1+%{host}+2"
  }
}

mutate {
  remove_field => [ "host" ]
}
```

ends up with to the following field content in the `custom` field:

`Hello, 1-name,ip-192-168-92-212,foo-6.4.2 baz-2`.

How did this happen?
I exptexted only: `Hello, 1+foo-6.4.2 baz+2`

Where do the beginning of the field coming from?

The `beat` field contains the following data:

```
beat.name          |  beat.hostname      |  beat.version
ip-192-168-92-212  |  ip-192-168-92-212  |  6.4.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed the `host` field to `myHost` then the `custom` field became what I expected.

It looks the `host` variable is already existing - but as a hidden field or something - but it is not sent to the ES.